# Maps in Xamarin Forms and MVVM architecture

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

How can I show maps in Xamarin Forms and MVVM architecture.How can I create a postion on a map in ModelView and show this in PageView?

View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:ExtendedContentPage xmlns:d="clr-namespace:TestApp;assembly=TestApp"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="TestApp.MapPageView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="30">
        <maps:Map WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="200"
            Text="{Binding MapModel.MyMap]"
            IsShowingUser="true"
            MapType="Hybrid"/>
  </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
</d:ExtendedContentPage>
```

ModelView

```
public class MapViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    private MapModel _mapModel = null;
    private MapModel MapModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _mapModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_mapModel != value)
            {
                _mapModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public MapViewModel(INavigation navigation) : base(navigation)
    {
        InitializeMapsPosition();
    }

    private  void InitializeMapsPosition()
    {

    }

    public override void RemoveHandlers()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class MapModel
{
    public string MyMap { set; get; }

    public MapModel(String myMap) 
    {
        MyMap = myMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my scenario I needed to show position of some places and current location in map. 
I used Xamarin.Forms.Maps to show map
and for locations in map : I added a CustomMap class and write two property injection to show pins in map.One property (CenterRegion) for showing current location and another one (CustomPins) for showing places location in map.

CustomMap Class

```
  public class CustomMap : Map
{
    private static IList<Pin> AllPins;

    public Location CenterRegion
    {
        get { return (Location)GetValue(CenterRegionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CenterRegionProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty CenterRegionProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(CenterRegion), returnType: 
       typeof(Location), declaringType: typeof(CustomMap), defaultValue: null, 
       propertyChanged: (sender, oldValue, newValue) =>
       {
           CustomMap map = (CustomMap)sender;

           if (newValue is Location location)
           {
               map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new 
               Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), 
               Distance.FromMiles(3)));
           }
       });


    public IEnumerable CustomPins
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(CustomPinsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomPinsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CustomPinsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(CustomPins), returnType: 
        typeof(IEnumerable), declaringType: typeof(CustomMap), defaultValue: null, 
        propertyChanged: (sender, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            CustomMap map = (CustomMap)sender;

            AllPins = new List<Pin>();

            map.Pins.Clear();

            if (newValue is IEnumerable spaces)
            {
                foreach (Pin pin in ConvertSpacesToPins(spaces))
                       map.Pins.Add(pin);
            }
            AllPins = map.Pins;
            map.OnPropertyChanged("Pins");
        });


    public static List<Pin> ConvertSpacesToPins(IEnumerable spaces)
    {
        if (spaces == null)
            return null;

        List<Pin> result = new List<Pin>();

        foreach (SpaceDto space in spaces.OfType<SpaceDto>())
        {
            double latitude = space.Latitude;
            double longitude = space.Longitude;
            string spaceTitle = space.Title;
            Position position = new Position(latitude, longitude);

            Pin pin = new Pin
            {
                Position = position,
                Label = spaceTitle
            };
                result.Add(pin);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Xaml page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:Map="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsPrismMapSample.Views"
                 x:Class="XamarinFormsPrismMapSample.Views.CustomMapSampleView">
        <Map:CustomMap
                    CenterRegion="{Binding CurrentLocation}"
                    CustomPins="{Binding Spaces}"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    IsShowingUser="true"
                    MapType="Street"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </ContentPage>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CustomMapSampleViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public Location CurrentLocation { get; set; }
        public SpaceDto Spaces { get; set; }

        public CustomMapSampleViewModel()
        {

        }

        public async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            Location CurrentLocation = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            List<SpaceDto> Spaces = new List<SpaceDto> { 
            new SpaceDto { Latitude = 45.6892 , Longitude = 51.3890, Title = "X"  }, 
            new SpaceDto { Latitude = 45.6891, Longitude = 51.3890, Title = "Y" }, 
            new SpaceDto { Latitude = 45.6888, Longitude = 51.3890, Title = "Z" } };
        }
    }

    public class SpaceDto
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual double Latitude { get; set; }
        public virtual double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If I could give you 10 upgrades I would!  I don't understand everything you did in CustomMap but it works perfectly!  I had been searching high and low for a way of moving the map to an arbitrary location and placing pins in my MVVM project.

Comment: I've almost got this implementation working. It works fine if the Spaces property is set on loading the viewmodel but if adding SpaceDto's in runtime to the property, nothing is updated on the map? I'm not using BindableBase but rather the property is an ObservableColletion decorated as ObservableProperty and the viewmodel is inheriting from ObservableObject provided by Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel if that matters?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Map.Pins` is not bindable, but there is `ItemsSource`, which is [easy to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins#display-a-pin-collection) instead.

```xaml
   <maps:Map ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
        <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pin Position="{Binding Position}"
                          Label="{Binding Name}"
                          Address="{Binding Subtitle}" />
```

So, just for the pins, *MVVM* can be done without any custom control.
But `Map.MoveToRegion()` (and `Map.VisibleRegion` to read) is still open. There should be a way to bind them. Why not both in a single read/write property? *(Answer: because of an endless loop.)*

Note: if you need `Map.MoveToRegion` only once on start, the region can be set in the constructor.